# c# named pipe two way communcation

Tags: c#, c++, ipc, named-pipes

I have two programs written in c++ and c#.I want to establish a two way communication using named-pipe between them. The C# client program can be connected to the named-pipe created by c++ server program.But nothing received in both ends.

Here is the c++ part (Server):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define UNICODE
using namespace std;
HANDLE hnamedPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
BOOL Finished =false;
HANDLE hThread = NULL;
unsigned long __stdcall CS_RcvThr(void * pParam) ;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    hnamedPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        "\\\\.\\pipe\\vikeyP",
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE|
        PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE|
        PIPE_WAIT,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
        1024,
        1024,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
        NULL);

    if(hnamedPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Failed" << endl;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        cout<< "Waiting for client"<< endl;
        if(!ConnectNamedPipe(hnamedPipe,NULL))
        {
            if(ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED != GetLastError())
            {
                cout << "FAIL"<< endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Connected!"<<endl;
            hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, &CS_RcvThr, NULL, 0, NULL);
            if(hThread) cout<<"read thread created"<<endl; else cout<<"cant crat rd thed\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"lst loop"<<endl;
        //Send over the message
        char chResponse[] = "hello\n";
        DWORD cbResponse,cbWritten;
        cbResponse = sizeof(chResponse);

        if (!WriteFile(
        hnamedPipe,
        chResponse,
        cbResponse,
        &cbWritten,
        NULL))
        {
            wprintf(L"failiure w/err 0x%08lx\n",GetLastError);
        }
        cout<<"Sent bytes :)" << endl;
        Sleep(10);
    }
}

unsigned long __stdcall CS_RcvThr(void * pParam) {
    BOOL fSuccess; 
    char chBuf[100];
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(chBuf);
    DWORD cbRead;
    int i;

    while (1)
    {
        fSuccess =ReadFile( hnamedPipe,chBuf,dwBytesToWrite,&cbRead, NULL); 
        if (fSuccess)
        {
            printf("C++ App: Received %d Bytes : ",cbRead);
            for(i=0;i<cbRead;i++)
                printf("%c",chBuf[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        if (! fSuccess && GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA) 
        {
            printf("Can't Read\n");
            if(Finished)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the C# part (Client):

```
    private Thread vikeyClientThread;
    public void ThreadStartClient()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread client started ID ={0} name = {1} " ,
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "vikeyP"))
        {
            // The connect function will indefinately wait for the pipe to become available
            // If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to ViKEY server...");
            pipeStream.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected :)");

            //Write from client to server
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeStream);
            while (true)
            {
                //Read server reply
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream);
                string temp = "";
                sw.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now);
                byte[] c = new byte[200];
                temp = sr.ReadLine();  
                pipeStream.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("RX =:{0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(c, 0, c.Length));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Vikey pipe Closed");
        Console.WriteLine("Thread with ID ={0} name = {1} is closed.",
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Whats happening though? Where is the error? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? What Console outputs are happening?

Comment: @misha130 In C# console it should print "hello" and in C++ console it should sent current date and time.

Comment: Did you try 'c++ to c++' or 'c# to c#' ? May be, it's not a problem from using different languages...

Comment: @dieter There are no problems with cross language use of pipes. I've done it without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the server side up as a message type vs byte type. If you want to read an arbitrary number of bytes, you'll need to use a byte type named pipe.

You're wrapping the stream in 2 objects one StreamReader and one StreamWriter. Don't do that, just use a Stream. You're trying to read by line, don't do that either. Instead send the number of bytes to read followed by the bytes. On the client side you'll read the byte count then create a buffer big enough then read. If it's text data you then would use an encoder (probably ASCII) to translate it back into a C# string.

Your while(true) should instead detect when the server has closed the pipe.

You should probably look into using an asynchronous named pipe.